Need Help Proving that $\mathbb{R}$ is a cogenerator of $\textbf{Vect}$
I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is a co-generator of $\textbf{Vect}$. Recall that $B'$ is a co-generator of a category $\mathscr{B}$ is the collection of arrow $f:B \rightarrow B'$ is mono, for some $B \in \mathscr{B}$.
I started by considering a function $\psi: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and noticing that this should be a linear function (for any two distinct vectors, we need to have two distinct real numbers). However, I know that linearly dependency of vectors is something that must be considered: if we just send define $\phi(u)=1$ and $\phi(v)=0$, when we are dealing with $v=2u$, for example, we are going to have problem.  So I thought of separating it in two cases:
If $u,v$ are linearly independent vectors, I could send $u$ to 0 and $v$ to 1 and complete to have a basis.
If $u,v$ are linearly dependent, I suspect it is enough to just $u$ to 1 and then complete (only $u$) to have a basis.
Is this correct? If not, how should I proceed?
Thanks in advance!

Does the definition of a cogenerator make sense to you?

I think so? But now I am starting to have some doubts... I believe it is enough to define one monomorphism in order to have a co-generator. But here, I believe I need to take into account the linear dependence/independence of vectors, no?

I don't think you have the right definition. In general, an object $X$ in a category is a cogenerator for that category if any two morphisms $f_1, f_2 : A \to B$ can be distinguished by maps $B \to X$. Specifically, if $g \circ f_1 = g \circ f_2$ for all $g : B \to X$, then $f_1 = f_2$. This can be phrased as the maps $\hom(A, g) : \hom(A, B) \to \hom(A, X)$ for all $g : B \to X$ are jointly monic.
Specializing that to the situation you're looking at, you'd want to prove that for any linear maps $T_1, T_2, : V \to W$, if $S \circ T_1 = S \circ T_2$ for every linear functional $S : W \to \mathbb{R}$, then $T_1 = T_2$. One way to approach this is to first prove that linear functionals separate points, in that if $f(x) = f(y)$ for every linear functional $f$, then $x = y$. Then use that to prove that $T_1(x) = T_2(x)$ for every $x$.
